# Background transparent is not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a dropdown with a transparent background. It works fine in Chrome but in Safari the `select` has this grey gradient background.

This is my CSS:

```css
div.controls {
  div.wrapper {
    select {
      background: transparent;
      border: none;
      color: blue;
      width: 100px;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;

      option {
        width: 200px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the default [appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance) of the `select`-element by using:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Alternatively you can use [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all):

```
all: unset;
```

#### Example:

```css
.a {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: blue;
  width: 100px;
}

.b {
  all: unset;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Default</option>
</select>

<select class="a">
  <option>Appearance</option>
</select>

<select class="b">
  <option>All</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But this will remove the dropdown arrow.

Comment: @saralance True that. That's the tradeoff for disabling the default styling, I guess.

Comment: also looking for a solution that keeps the arrow, but without the background - as you can get it in Gecko and Blink. Otherwise `all: unset` would be a more cross browser version of the above.

Comment: @retrovertigo Good point. I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks.